# swfrender (swftools) batch output to png

Tags: flash

I have hundreds of swf (single page) files numbered 01.swf ...121.swf

I want to batch convert them into png, I'm using swfrender from swftools and I use MAC OSX.

How can I batch convert?

This one doest work

swfrender file[01-02].swf -o output.png

Answer (score 2):

Using bash:

```
for x in *.swf; do
    swfrender ${x} -o ${x%.swf}.png
done
```

Although I would use

```
    swfrender -X 1836 -Y 2376 ${x} -o ${x%.swf}.png
```

for a US Letter Size page that is at least marginally readable (about 200 dpi).

Answer (score 1):

I am no shell expert thats why I will use a python code to do this

```
import os
for i in range(0,10):
    os.system("swfrender file%02d.swf -o output.png" % i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a higher resolution than the one obtained from swfrender, you can try out the free Adobe AIR application 
[Kurst SWF Renderer 1.0](http://swfrenderer.kurst.co.uk/) from Karim Beyrouti, or the commercial SWF Renderer 2.0

Screenshot shows setting for 300% scaling:

[image: Kurst_SWF_Renderer]